# How to disable HWE messages (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, hardware-enablement-stack

As almost everyone who installed their Ubuntu 14.04 a while ago, I started getting the HWE messages every time.

Now, I DO NOT WANT the latest HWE. Opting-out of kernel & graphics drivers updates.

So far so good, right? The messages, however, keep popping up every single day. This is beyond annoying. There is no FAQ, option or explanation of how to get rid of these. So here I am asking for help. :)

How do I disable this pop-up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running an old HWE stack you will no longer be receiving updates to the kernel and Xorg stack and as such you won't receive security updates.  That being said if you really want to disable it do the following:

```
sudo touch /var/lib/update-notifier/disable-hwe-eol-messages
```

Comment: Gave it a try, will update once I figure out how to test if this works. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can test it by running "hwe-support-status --show-replacements" with and without the file in place.  With the file in place no replacements will be shown - update-manager uses hwe-support-status under the hood.

Comment: This is great workaround against latest video drivers incompatibility introduced in latest kernel for Ubuntu 14.04